# 1045-Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Tags: laravel-7, migrate, php-7.4

I am working with laravel 7 and after clone my existing repo which was created via windows operating system and right now i am using macOS.
After cloning I copy .env.example and converted into .env file and then run the below commands,

1. `composer install`
2. `npm install && npm run dev`
3. `php artisan key:generate`

All of the above commands run perfectly and then i run the 4 number commands to seed the database.

4. `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

After run the `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`, I have faced an error  `[1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Then I checked the php version and it showed `php version: 8` and that's why I **downgrade** the php version from `version 8 to 7.4` and right now the requires version are given below,

- **PHP Version:** `7.4.30`
- **Composer Version:** `2.4.1`

then I clone again and run the same commands 1,2,3 and 4 but iot's sorrow that I have faced same error again. Please check the attached file and check the error and help me to solve the error.

[image: migrate related issues in laravel 71]

Answer (score 2):

That indicates a problem with your database connection. Your Laravel application is not able to connect to the MySQL database. Check that mysql is running and that you have the correct database name, port, user, and password for your mysql client, or try connecting to mysql outside of the application.

Once you have completed the preceding steps and are able to connect to MySQL from outside of the application, you can run:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Comment: Already I did it @HariUpreti

Comment: Are you able to connect with MySql outside from laravel application ?

Comment: Yea, but i don't know why I didn't solve this issue and that's why I am uninstalling and want re install it

Comment: Are you using MAMP on mac ? try adding root as your db password once
Ex:

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databaseName
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

Comment: No, I am using XAMPP..

Comment: Does your XMPP show mysql is running or it shows some issue while running MySql ? It is for sure that you are having issue with mysql connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I solved these issues reinstalling XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe 2 problems with your database connection.

Try to write correct database username and password at your .env file, in case you have created manually,

OR

If you are working on existing database, then try to create new user for your my sql database,
Open your mysql database go to privileges, add new user for your database and set password, then rewrite the username and password at .env file.

[image: myql db]

Answer (score 0):

Try DB_PASSWORD="somepass" instead of DB_PASSWORD=somepass , in your .env files it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).